# While loop still running even when the condition is false

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have been  working on a tic-tac-toe project, however, there's a problem:

```
intro()

row_top = [' ','|',' ','|',' ']
line = ['-','-','-','-','-']
row_mid = [' ','|',' ','|',' ']
row_low = [' ','|',' ','|',' ']

default = (' ' in row_top or ' ' in row_mid or ' ' in row_low)

p1 = True

while default:

    while p1 :

        p1c = int(input('P1 turn! insert the position you want to place the marker:'))

        if inserter_1(p1c) != 'Error':
            display()
            p1 = False

    while not p1:

        p2c = int(input('P2 turn! insert the position you want to place the marker:'))

        if inserter_2(p2c) != 'Error':
            display()
            p1 = True

winner_check()
```

The `inserter()` function changes the value of the space strings to 'X' or 'O' and the display() function prints out the board.

Even the `display()` function shows that the board has been filled(Which means that there's no ' ' in all of the rows), it still asks for inputs.

The thing that was really confusing is that the *default* condition is definitely false, I even tried to add a list of numbers from 1 to 9 and remove a number every time the player's inputs but it still isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you updating `default`, looks like it is evaluated as `True` and then not called again to change when an update has been made. This will not change in place as the board changes.

Comment: Can you share ```intro()```, ```display()```

Comment: You want to turn `default` into a function, and _call_ that function every time you want to evaluate it. The thing is, it would be super costly for a program to always re-evaluate values of variables, so you don't want to do that. Variables are used to evaluate things once and store that information somewhere,  so that there is no need to re-evaluate things multiple times (and simplify code). In this case you could also just replace `default` with the expression you have as variable value?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I posted the wrong version of my code, I actually change 'while default' into 'while ' ' in row_top or ' ' in row_mid or ' ' in row_low' but it swill works the same

Answer (score 3):

Heres a little Quiz, how often do you think the expression is evaluated?
It is once when the code reaches default =.
You seem to think that default is reevaluated every time, but it just carries True forever as it is never changed.
Try replacing default with the expression used in the while loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I posted the wrong version of my code, I actually change 'while default' into 'while ' ' in row_top or ' ' in row_mid or ' ' in row_low' but it swill works the same

Answer (score 0):

there are some edges case regarding " ". I tested "default" on jupyter notebook:

[image]

Now pay attention to row_top[0]. it is not filled but returns false

[image]

Look at this. supposed to return true but returns false. I change the condition of `default`from ' ' to '' to be aware of small changes.

[image]

one more edge case:

[image]

When manipulating the state, it is breaking the logic